# Problem with Inheritance

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext

Can anyone tell me is there a way to inherit from a base class when using the DataContext and LINQ to SQL? I have the following class:

```
[Table(Name="names")]
public class person : IPerson, INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private int ID;
    private string Fname;
    private string Mname;
    .....

    [Column]
    public string firstname
    {
    }
}
```

Then, I have the inherited class:

```
public class child : person
{
    private int isActive;

    [Column]
    public int isactive
    {
    }

    public child(string firstname,...., int isactive):base(firstname,....)
    {
    }
}
```

My data access class is as follows:

```
[Database]
public class dataxist : DataContext
{
    public dataxist(string username, string servername, string pword,
        string dbname) : base(@"uid=" + username + ";server=" + servername + ";pwd='"          + pword + "'" +
            ";database=" + dbname + ";")
    {

    }

    public Table<names> names;
}
```

When I attempt to make an insert using the child class I get a object reference null error on the `InsertOnSubmit()` call although the my child object is not `null` (Note: I'm passing in an object then checking the type to determine if it is a person or child object then casting to the proper object:

```
databaseInfo.child c = (databaseInfo.child)n;
cd.names.InsertOnSubmit(c);
```

When my child object inherits from the person object does it inherit the `[Table(Names="names")]` attribute as well? or not? Any suggestions?

Comment: Just so you know, the [`TableAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.tableattribute.aspx) is not inherited.

Comment: It appears to me that you are hand-rolling your LinqToSql classes.  It is worth noting that the API was never designed to support this style.  If you set up your classes even *slighly* wrong, you will get enigmatic exceptions that do not even remotely help you figure out what you did wrong.  Is there a reason you are not generating your classes via the designer?

Comment: Basically, I wanted to have a base class that I can inherit from (eg. Person and have inherited classes such as child, adult, or etc.) The designer creates one class from the table. This table has fields for multiple classes. That's why I'm trying to break it out.

Comment: You can use the designer to map multiple classes in an inheritance hierarchy from a single table. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399352.aspx

Comment: You can create partial classes.